# jQuery Mobile swipeleft and swiperight not very responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I am creating a mobile app with `PhoneGap` and want to get some `swiperight` and `swipeleft` functionality working. I decided on using jQuery mobile `swipeleft` and `swipeleft`, but it is not very responsive at all. It takes 3 swipes in either direction in order for my code to detect a `swipeleft` or `swiperight`. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is jQuery the wrong choice? Or is it something I am doing? Any help is much appreciated.

Here are two ways in which I tried to get it to work:

1)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $( "div.box" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    alert("in swipe");
  }

});
```

2)

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){

 $("div.box").swiperight(function() {
   alert("in swipe");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, yes - it's the wrong choice.

I used to use jQM for my PG apps and I found the same as you; swiping is just not responsive enough. I used other UI elements instead and then found Ionic which has a perfectly responsive swipe.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery was actually the wrong choice for detecting a swipeleft or swiperight. I used an open source library called Hammer. Here it is: http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/ .